# How to use custom component variable in custom component stylesheet?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

Let's say I have a custom component - WoodComponent (/src/components/wood/wood.ts):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'wood',
  templateUrl: 'wood.html'
})
export class WoodComponent {
  color: string = 'brown';
  constructor() {}
}
```

How would I use the color variable in the component's stylesheet  (/src/components/wood/wood.scss)? E.g.:

```
wood {
  .wood-selected {
    background-color: color($colors, [color variable from component]);
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `brown` inside `variables.scss` file and then use as shown below.

*variables.scss*

```
colors: ( primary: #488aff, brown: brown);
```

*.scss*

```
wood {
  .wood-selected {
    background-color: color($colors, brown);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sampath. "brown" is the value of the "color" variable and will change. "brown" could be anything, so, unless I'm missing something, I'm not sure declaring "brown" in variables.scss is going to help!